# Trying to use a regular expression in R to capture some data

Tags: regex, r, stringr

So I have a table in R, and an example of of the string I am trying to capture is this:

```
C.Hale (79-83)
```

I want to write a regular expression to extract the (79-83).

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: you can also go to https://regex101.com/ to play around regex

Comment: You could also do `regmatches(x, regexpr("\\(.*\\)", x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`.   We match one or more characters that are not a space (`[^ ]+`) from the beginning of the string (`^`) , followed by a space (`\\s`) and replace it with a `''`.

```
sub('^[^ ]+\\s', '', str1)
#[1] "(79-83)"
```

Or another option is `stri_extract_all` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '\\([^)]+\\)')[[1]]
#[1] "(79-83)"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'C.Hale (79-83)'
```

Comment: Awesome this worked. How about just extracting the name, and also extracting the wins column (79) and the losses column (83)?

Comment: @SpencerNelson Try `l1 <- strsplit(str1, ' |-|[()]'); do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, function(x) x[nzchar(x)]))`

Comment: Never heard of stringi package before. Thanks  @akrun

Answer (score 3):

One possibility using the **qdapRegex** package I maintain:

```
x <- "C.Hale (79-83)"

library(qdapRegex)
rm_round(x, extract = TRUE, include.markers = TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "(79-83)"
```

Comment: Or using `rm_between` : `rm_between(str1, "(", ")", extract = T, include.markers = T)`